# Simple data, Complex query on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a query over an SQL Server table but I don't know exactly how.

Consider this table (the real table is much more complex, Ord1 and Ord2 are dates that could be null, but i simplified it to this case):

**Data of MyTable**

```
ID  MaqID   Ord1    Ord2 
------------------------
1   144     4       3 
2   144     2       1 
3   12      2       3 
4   144     3       5 
5   12      3       1
6   144     4       2 
7   12      2       4 
8   144     2       3 
9   12      1       5 
10  12      3       2
```

I need records for specific MaqID in Specific Order. I get that with this Query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MaqID=144 ORDER BY MaqID, Order1 DESC, Order2
```

Wich give me:

```
ID  MaqID   Ord1    Ord2
------------------------
6   144     4       2
1   144     4       3
4   144     3       5
2   144     2       1
8   144     2       3
```

Now, I need a single query that, for each MaqID, return the first ID for each subquery following above order. The result should be:

**Expected result**

```
MaqID    ID
-----------
144      6
12       5
```

I have already try distinct conbination of TOP a MAX, but TOP result only one result and i need one for each MaqID, and for Max I have not field to maximize.

**To sumarize:** I need the first ID for each MaqID from a subquery in a specific order

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Complex? What is complex on that? COmplex is hal a page or longer SQL. Which sql server version?

Comment: Suggest you look at row_number in books online and also Ord1, Ord2? Perhaps a child table would be a better choice for a design.

Comment: Sorry @TomTom is complex for my understanding. SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @HLGEM i will look at row_number. The real ORDER clause involves 3 fields with a CASE to eliminate NULL value and datetime values. I make it numeric for simplify the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by macid Order1 DESC, Order2) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I'll adapt this to my real case and try it. Thank you.

Comment: Could be that your query has syntax errors? i try it like this and get it to work:select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by macid ORDER BY Order1 DESC, Order2) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1; Is this correct?

Comment: I thnik you miss the Order By and the t as alias after myTable